# Catch trigger's exceptions from db in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

How to catch triggers exceptions in Django admin site when you add or edit records?
For example I have model

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    flight_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    departure_time = models.TimeField()
    arrival_time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.flight_num
```

and trigger in PostgreSQL 9.1

```
BEGIN
    if (NEW.departure_time > NEW.arrival_time)
    then raise EXCEPTION 'It's unreal';
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

The model is registered in admin.site. Thank you.

Comment: usually that sort of logic is handled in python: in your FlightModel form validation or by overriding the Flight.save method.  Could you post the exact exception that is being raised?